# How to capture current users Name and Email

Tags: visualforce, contact, record

Work in a very large org and I have a VF button/page which shows a set of product fields that the teams are asked to edit/update

I would like to capture the user and email in a separate field so I can run workflow emails against the two fields.

I have seen where the current user ID and email is displayed but I havent seen how it can be populated and captured upon save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `UserInfo.getUserId()` in Apex code to get the ID, and probably a similar method to get the e-mail. You could call it when you call your VF page (assuming you have a custom apex controller).

Comment: CODE :<apex:page standardController="Device__c">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Device__c.label} Edit / Submit" subtitle="{!Device__c.name}"/>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Device__c.label} Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:page>

Comment: </apex:page>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Device" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Device__c.XXX}"/>

Comment: Would I need to create a separate controller outside of the Device__c controller? And thank you for your help! Im an admitted newby and this has stumped me

Comment: You would need to create a custom controller to do this, yes. But it isn't that bad, since you can do whatever you need in a standard controller page. You will need to look up some info on how to select the files to update, but that isn't that hard, I think.

Also, as I said, you can use [this method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUserEmail) to get the e-mail address of the current user in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable `$User` in your visualforce page or you can use it in Apex also.

Check this - [Global variable $User in VF](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_user.htm)

Like Reneto said, you can use `UserInfo` as well in case you need in Apex.

Comment: CODE :<apex:page standardController="Device__c"> <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Device__c.label} Edit / Submit" subtitle="{!Device__c.name}"/> <apex:form > <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Device__c.label} Edit" mode="edit"> <apex:pageBlockButtons > <apex:page>

Comment: </apex:page> <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/> <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/> </apex:pageBlockButtons> <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Device" columns="2"> <apex:inputField value="{!Device__c.XXX}"/>

Comment: Would I need to create a separate controller outside of the Device__c controller? And thank you for your help! Im an admitted newby and this has stumped me

Comment: HI @Drew Mora, Can you please update your question with code.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, please see my first two comments, I tried to split the top section of code for my VF page in two scetions. Let me know if you were looking for something different.